# Confusing main effect in mixed design ANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, mixed-model

I am conducting a mixed design ANOVA test using ezANOVA. I ran two different tests as follows:

Test1: within subject variable *w*, between subject variables *age* and *x1*.

Test2: within subject variable *w*, between subject variables *age* and *x2*.

Both tests are on the same data and same dependent variable (but I built two separate models), all independent variables are categorical.

But the output shows that, in Test1, the main effect of *age* is not significant, but in Test2 it is significant. My question is if this can happen or I am doing something wrong? In both tests, interaction between *age* and *x1*/*x2* are not significant.

Comment: Maybe need to write down the model mathematically. Did you fit two models and perform one test on each of them, or fit one model and test two hypotheses based on the same model?

Comment: I had two separate models

Comment: Could you write down you two models mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common occurrence, and I'm sure there has to be a good explanation on Cross Validated somewhere. But I'll mention a couple of things.

- *Adding terms uses up denominator degrees of freedom in the F test for the other terms*.  In your case, if `x1` is a factor variable with more levels than `x2`, the sums of squares for `Age` could be the same for both models, but the F-test could be different based on the denominator degrees of freedom.
- *Correlated independent variables*.  When independent variables are correlated, the shared sum of squares may be assigned to only one term, or only the unique sum of squares for a term may be counted.  I think it's always a good idea to check the correlations among all independent variables, and between the dependent variable and each independent variable, as a preliminary step.
- *Types of sums of squares can  matter*.  You probably know that `stats::anova` uses type I sum of squares.  `car::Anova` uses type II by default.  I don't know what type `ezANOVA` uses by default.  In any case, using these different types affects how the sums of squares are apportioned to terms, and so affects the F-tests.